# How does a system wide profiler (e.g. perf) correlate counters with instructions?

Tags: performance, optimization, linux-kernel, operating-system, profiling

I'm trying to understand how a system wide profiler works. Let's take **linux perf** as example. For a certain profiling time it can provide:

- Various aggregated hadware performance counters
- Time spent and hardware counters (e.g. #instructions) for each user space process and kernel space function
- Information about context switches
- etc.

The first thing I'm almost sure about is that the report is just an estimation of what's really happening. So I think there's some kernel module that **launches software interrupts at a certain sampling rate**. The lower the sampling rate, the lower the profiler overhead. The interrupt can read the model specific registers that store the performance counters.

The next part is to correlate the counters with the software that's running on the machine. *That's the part I don't understand*.

1. So where does the profiler gets its data from?
2. **Can you interrogate for example the task scheduler to find out what was running when you interrupted him?** Won't that affect the
   execution of the scheduler (e.g. instead of continuing the
   interrupted function it will just schedule another one, making the
   profiler result not accurate). Is the list of **task_struct** objects available?
3. How can profilers even correlate HW
   metrics even at instruction level?

Comment: There are two things in profiling. Counting and sampling. Counting measures the
overall
number
of events during the entire execution without offering any insight
regarding
the
instructions or functions that
generated
them
. On
the other hand,
sampling gives a correlation of
the events to the code
through captured samples of the Instruction Pointer
.http://openlab.web.cern.ch/sites/openlab.web.cern.ch/files/technical_documents/TheOverheadOfProfilingUsingPMUhardwareCounters.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So I think there's some kernel module that launches software interrupts at a certain sampling rate.

Perf is not module, it is part of the Linux kernel, implemented in 
[kernel/events/core.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.16/source/kernel/events/core.c) and for every supported architecture and cpu model, for example [arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event*.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.16/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event.c). But Oprofile was a module, with similar approach.

Perf generally works by asking PMU (Performance monitoring unit) of CPU to generate interrupt after N events of some hardware performance counter  ([Yokohama, slide 5](http://halobates.de/modern-pmus-yokohama.pdf) "*• Interrupt when threshold reached: allows sampling*"). Actually it may be implemented as:

- select some PMU counter
- initialize it to `-N`, where N is the sampling period (we want interrupt after N events, for example, after 2 millions of cycles `perf record -c 2000000 -e cycles`, or some N computed and tuned by perf when no extra option is set or `-F` is given)
- set this counter to wanted event, and ask PMU to generate interrupt on overflow (ARCH_PERFMON_EVENTSEL_INT). It will happen after N increments of our counter.

All modern Intel chips supports this, for example, Nehalem: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/76/87/30320 - Nehalem Performance Monitoring Unit Programming Guide

> EBS - Event Based Sampling. A technique in which counters are pre-loaded with a large negative count, and they are configured to interrupt the processor on overflow. When the counter overflows the interrupt service routine capture profiling data.

So, when you use hardware PMU, there is no additional work at timer interrupt with special reading of hardware PMU counters. There is some work to save/restore PMU state at task switch, but this (`*_sched_in`/`*_sched_out` of kernel/events/core.c) will not change PMU counter value for current thread nor will export it to user-space.

There is a handler: [`arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event.c: x86_pmu_handle_irq`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.16/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event.c#L1222) which finds the overflowed counter and [calls](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.16/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event.c#L1264) `perf_sample_data_init(&data, 0, event->hw.last_period);` to record the current time, IP of last executed command (it can be inexact because of out-of-order nature of most Intel microarchitetures, there is limited workaround for some events - PEBS, `perf record -e cycles:pp`), stacktrace data (if `-g` was used in record), etc. Then handler resets the counter value to the `-N` (x86_perf_event_set_period, `wrmsrl(hwc->event_base, (u64)(-left) & x86_pmu.cntval_mask);` - note the minus before `left`)

> The lower the sampling rate, the lower the profiler overhead.

Perf allows you to set target sampling rate with `-F` option, `-F 1000` means  around 1000 irq/s. High rates are not recommended due to high overhead. Ten years ago Intel VTune recommended not more than 1000 irq/s (http://www.cs.utah.edu/~mhall/cs4961f09/VTune-1.pdf "*Try to get about a 1000 samples per second per logical CPU.*"), perf usually don't allow too high rate for non-root (autotuned to lower rate when "perf interrupt took too long" - check in your `dmesg`; also check `sysctl -a|grep perf`, for example `kernel.perf_cpu_time_max_percent=25` - which means that perf will try to use not more then 25 % of CPU)

> Can you interrogate for example the task scheduler to find out what was running when you interrupted him?

No. But you can enable tracepoint at `sched_switch` or other sched event (list all available in sched: `perf list 'sched:*'`), and use it as profiling event for the perf. You can even ask perf to record stacktrace at this tracepoint:

```
 perf record -a -g -e "sched:sched_switch" sleep 10
```

> Won't that affect the execution of the scheduler

Enabled tracepoint will make add some perf event sampling work to the function with tracepoint

> Is the list of task_struct objects available?

Only via ftrace...

> Information about context switches

This is software perf event, just call to `perf_sw_event` with `PERF_COUNT_SW_CONTEXT_SWITCHES` event from sched/core.c (indirectly). Example of direct call - migration software event: [kernel/sched/core.c  set_task_cpu()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.16/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L1068): `p->se.nr_migrations++; perf_sw_event(PERF_COUNT_SW_CPU_MIGRATIONS, 1, NULL, 0);`

PS: there are good slides on perf, ftrace and other profiling and tracing subsystems in Linux by Gregg: http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty much answers all three of your questions.

Profiling consits of two types: Counting and sampling. Counting measures the
overall
number
of events during the entire execution without offering any insight
regarding
the
instructions or functions that
generated
them
. On
the other hand,
sampling gives a correlation of
the events to the code
through captured samples of the Instruction Pointer
.
When sampling, the
kernel instructs the processor to issue an interrupt when
a chosen
event counter exceeds a
threshold. T
his interrupt is caught by the kernel and the sampled data
including the Instruction
Pointer
value are stored into a ring buffer. The buffer is polled periodically by the userspace
perf tool and its contents
written to disk.
In post processing, the Instruction Pointer is matched to
addresses in binary files, which can be translated into function names and such

Refer http://openlab.web.cern.ch/sites/openlab.web.cern.ch/files/technical_documents/TheOverheadOfProfilingUsingPMUhardwareCounters.pdf

Comment: Ok. This starts to confirm some of my suppositions. However I'm not very sure that the interrupt is issued when a counter reaches the threshold. I think that there is just a simple timer that collects samples at each tick. We don't really know a-priori what the value of the counters would be in order to set the threshold. Possibly the answer may be a mix of both methods. Regarding the IP, won't that point to the interrupt routine. How can we get the IP of the interrupted task?

Comment: @VAndrei: The way interrupts have more or less always worked is the microcode for each instruction says "Is the interrupt request set?" and if so it basically starts an unrequested function call to the interrupt handler. The handler can simply look at the stack to see where it was called from, which is the IP of the interrupted process.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I read some more and I understand now that when servicing an IR (even if it's software), the handler saves the information of the running task. I doubt however that the microcode of each instruction polls for hardware interrupt requests. That would mean that one of the execution ports will always be busy with the poll. It may be a hard wired routine (e.g. ARM's Generic Interrupt Controller)

Comment: @VAndrei, in the 21st century PMU is implemented as *separate hardware block*, which has lot of performance monitor inputs from different places of pipeline, and also has several counter registers (MSR) and control registers. With control register you commutate inputs to counters, and also can set the interrupt on overflow (https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779576860030/monitoring_Micro.pdf "*EBS performance-monitoring hardware typically generates a performance monitor interrupt when a performance event counter overflows*"). The interrupt may be served just as any other hw trap.

Comment: @osgx. Thanks for your answer. I know that the PMU is implemented as a HW block. The thing I thought is that the profiler generates a SW interrupt when the timer elapses. I now see that most likely the interrupt is generated by the PMU, when a certain counter overflows.