# Perf stack backtraces on armv7l

Tags: arm, armv7, perf, backtrace

I'm trying to use perf to get information about stack backtraces in my system.
I compile an application where main calls f, f calls g1, g1 calls g3, g3 calls g4, g4 calls g2.
I expect my backtrases to be something like

- g2
- g4
- g3
- g1
- f
- main

But instead, I have cropped backtraces in perf script, like

```
a.out  2869 [000] 19414.348571:     225426 cycles:ppp:
                     7ac f (/opt/usr/home/owner/a.out)
                beb3dd2c [unknown] ([unknown])

a.out  2869 [000] 19414.348754:     235721 cycles:ppp:
                     72c g1 (/opt/usr/home/owner/a.out)
                beb3dd24 [unknown] ([unknown])

a.out  2869 [000] 19414.348937:     246486 cycles:ppp:
                     670 g3 (/opt/usr/home/owner/a.out)
                beb3dd14 [unknown] ([unknown])

a.out  2869 [000] 19414.349121:     232929 cycles:ppp:
                     60c g4 (/opt/usr/home/owner/a.out)
                beb3dd04 [unknown] ([unknown])
```

How can I get more info about my backtraces?

Compile: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O0 -g3 -marm -fno-omit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables main.c

Perf record: perf record -g -a

Perf script: perf script

Target is running on Linux 3.10.65.

Answer (score 1):

There were problems with stack unwinding implementation in perf for ARM: Not implemented at some moment.
Try recent kernel and/or recent version of perf (new perf tool will work on old kernel, but part of backtrace reading is in kernel).

https://wiki.linaro.org/LEG/Engineering/TOOLS/perf-callstack-unwinding (also mentioned there: [How does linux's perf utility understand stack traces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277463))

> Linux perf has architecture specific support code. x86 has some dwarf stack frame unwinding support whilst arm and arm64 do not. It should be implemented on ARM32/64.
>   The work for ARMv7 is done under LEG-760 blueprint.  .. The expected result is the backtrace of user and kernel call chain in the perf output statistics.

Support was commited after september 2013: http://www.spinics.net/lists/kernel/msg1608919.html
and [3.10 is from june 2013](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.10).

Try kernel&perf from 3.11, or any newer version of kernel.