# Linux perf does not record function in libstdc++.so correctly

Tags: c++, profiler, perf

I am using perf to profile a C++ program. The code is like:

```
std::string generateRandomString() {
    // Initialize a random number generator
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    // Define a distribution for the length of the string (1 to 6)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> lenDistribution(1, 6);
    int length = lenDistribution(gen);

    // Define characters that can be part of the string
    const std::string characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    // Generate the random string
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> charDistribution(0, characters.size() - 1);
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        result += characters[charDistribution(gen)];
    }
    return result;
}


void test_trie(){
    for (...) generateRandomString();
}

void test(){
    // do something
}

int main(){
    test_trie();
    test();
}
```

Then

1. I compile it with `g++ -g -O2 main.cpp -o secmaster_test` (`-O0` is also tried)
2. profile it with `perf record -F 999 -g -- ./secmaster_test`
3. draw a flamegraph. like this
   [image]

But I think the result should be like follow:

```
                                           | --- some random -----|
                  | ...something...        | generateRandomString | -- --|
                  | ----------test-------- | --------------test_trie-----|
                  | ---------------------main----------------------------|
|--startup code-- | -------------------secmaster_test------------------- | -- cleanup -- |
```

Seems that `perf` somehow don't know functions about random is called in `main()` ?

BTW, I tried:

1. using `perf record --call-graph dwarf`
2. using `perf record --call-graph fp`

and failed

Comment: Looks like random was inlined and left no record in the dwarf information.

Comment: `random()` in the global namespace from `<cstdlib>` is in libc.so.6 and can't inline.  (And is quite slow, taking a lock to protect the process-wide seed).  Is this some other function in a different namespace you forgot to mention or show a `using` for?

Comment: Looks like you are really using C++ Pseudo-random number generation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random.

Comment: @PeterCordes actually it is not random(). complete code is updated above

Comment: `std::mt19937` member functions are presumably defined in headers so they can inline, like many other C++ standard library functions.

Comment: @PeterCordes So inlined functions cannot be recorded be perf? which means inlined function lost debug info somehow?

Comment: @PeterCordes I recompiled with `-fno-inline`, which doesn't change anything

Comment: It wouldn't do, since preventing inlining doesn't also force frame pointers, which are what you actually need.

Comment: Do you have libstdc++.so debug symbols installed? With debug symbols installed and `perf record --call-graph dwarf` you may get more detailed flamegraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the help of comments and answers.

Default compilation of stdlibc++ does not contain all frame pointers, so perf captures incorrect frame pointer. The solution is to recompile gcc (for c,c++, to get glibc and libstdc++)

Hereby is the steps for me:

1. download gcc 11.4
2. in gcc root dir, run `./contrib/download_prerequisites` to download prerequisites
3. run `mkdir build && cd build && ../configure CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-omit-frame-pointer" --enable-languages=c,c++  --disable-multilib` to configure gcc, maybe add more options like `--prefix=/path/to/install`
4. compile and install `make -j16 && make install`

Then compile program with new gcc/g++, will give correct FlameGraph.

Answer (score 0):

From the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38280294/212858):

> Always compile with frame pointers.
> [or]
> ... a workaround for missing frame pointers in user-level stacks: libunwind, which uses dwarf.

So, either build with

- `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` or
- `-g dwarf`

The frame pointer is the usual way perf (and other tools) "read" the call stack, and without it even a non-inlined function can be hard to identify.

DWARF debugging symbols are another way, but you have to ask the compiler to generate them.

Comment: with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` perf will provide more stack-trace information.
But doesn't solve the problem. I guess `std::random_device::_M_init` by libstdc++ is compiled without  `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, maybe I should recompile libstdc++?

Comment: Or you can just wrap the libstdc++ functions you want to see in your profile in your own non-inlined functions.